# Ubuntu for Dell Inspiron 1545 (Celeron Dual-Core CPU 1.80 GHz)

Tags: dell, inspiron

I installed Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) on my Acer Inspire One laptop with out any major problems. Now I want to install it on my Dell Inspiron Laptop, but the only versions I could find were 64bit for 2.xx GHz CPUs. I've checked various forums, but all the posts are (understandably from 3+ years ago. The most relevant reference I could find was about Ubuntu 9.04.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop truly is only 32bit, 32bit images can be obtained from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Just choose "32 bit" under flavor. You shouldn't have any compatibility issues with it at all.